# What is a good way of implementing a SSO strategy between different types of applications?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, meteor, single-sign-on

We currently have three different applications, the first one is a NodeJS + MySQL + Express +  Dojo (client side) with its own manual authentication scheme, the second one is a NodeJS + MySQL + Express + AngularJS (client side), also with its own authentication mechanism. The third one is a Meteor application, where it relies on the accounts library of Meteor for authentication.

Is there a good reference, library, framework, etc. which could help us in unifying the authentication mechanism in such a way that when you first authenticate, you share the authentication with all other applications?
If necessary, we would drop the authentication mechanism in each application and externalize it to a fourth one, with the sole purpose of managing authentications.
Are there good strategies or libraries for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A good way is to build a separate authentication app which then redirects with an encrypted token to your current applications.

http://merbist.com/2012/04/04/building-and-implementing-a-single-sign-on-solution/

Comment: Thanks, seems a useful link so as to organize the ideas.